# Predicting the amount of parents in a binary tree

Tags: c#, binary-tree

I'm trying to predict the amount of parents in a Binary tree given that it all you know is the amount of leaves, and its a balanced binary tree.

Currently, my code runs like this:

```
        int width = exits;
        int amountOfParents = 0;

        do
        {
            width -= 2;
            AmountOfParents++;
        } while (width > 0);
```

The basic premise of the code is that it will take all the child, and find the number of parents for them. Do this iteratively until you reach the root. However, the problem comes in when the height of the tree is uneven.

This solution gives correct number of parents up till 5. When it hits 6, the binaray tree creates another parent node, so there should be 4, but it gives 3. I know why it gives 3, but I don't know how to fix it.

Edit: I just had another idea. What if I find the closest <strike>perfect square number</strike> perfectly balanced tree, and than individually find the unaccounted? Trying now.

Comment: Your code is actually bad. You have variables which do something unobvious and extra variables (why do you need `amountOfParents` variable if you increase it once?).
Nobody can understand your algorithm if even you cannot do this.

Comment: @DoKZ It was just lefover code from previous tries. I've already edited it out from the question. Thanks for the point out.

Comment: Isn't it just roughly `n / 2`?

Comment: @Enigmativity No. Think about it, when you have 10 leaves, you will have 5 parents. Than parents of parents. Thus n / 2 is off the mark by quite a shot, since it doesn't take into account the parents of parents.

Comment: @user2418426 - Yes, of course. I think Servé might have it.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is log2(exits) * 2 + 1

C#: `Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(x) / Math.Log(2)) * 2 + 1;`

But it has to be perfectly balanced indeed

So since I'm doing the inverse of square numbers, your idea of the square numbers could work.

Comment: The square numbers isn't working out. I had it wrong; it shouldn't be square numbers, it needs to be 2,4,8,16... 2 ^ n numbers. This would ensure that it is a perfectly balanced tree on one side, while the imbalance is on the others. How do I check for the closest 2^n numbers in c# efficiently? The only way I can think of is a nested for loop, but it seems to be too crazy a job for something like this

Comment: well with log2(n) you get the depth of the tree. Multiply by 2 and +1 for the root node (2^0). It's not perfect but I think it's closest

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with several different methods, but this seems to be the best one.

You take the all the child and group them into pairs. Put the pairs into a list and do the same thing again. If there is an odd number of pairs, just put him into the list. He will get handled in later iterations due to the nature of it.